# Trying to use prepare and bindParam to insert user data into SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to insert user input into a MYSQL database. I am utilizing the `REPLACE INTO` because the column `email` has a unique key to prevent duplication. The table name is `launch_email`. I am trying to prevent SQL injection by using `prepare` and `bindParam`, however I keep getting this error: `Call to undefined function bindParam()`. Any solutions?

PHP/SQL:

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $replace = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES (:email_str)");
    $replace = bindParam(":email_str", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $replace->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
exit;
}
```

EDIT: The code below solved my problem. I was assigning a method to a non-object.

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $replace = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES (:email_str)");
    $replace->bindParam(":email_str", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $replace->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember bindParam is a method of the Classes PDO, MySQLi or whatever database you're using... So it must be called this way:

```
$replace->bindParam(":email_str", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: I now get this error instead: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Comment: Sorry. I've made a mistake. bindParam is a method of PDOStatement. It's solved now

Comment: That is exactly as I had it before and it was getting the initial error in the post.

Answer (score 0):

[PDOStatement::bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is a PDOStatement method .

this should work

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $stm = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES (:email_str)");
    $stm->bindParam(":email_str", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
exit;
}
```

Comment: I now get this error instead: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Comment: Error: 'Call to a member function execute() on a non-object'

Comment: @AbdouTahiri the PDOStatement::bindParam() method returns true or false. You just replaced the statement value with a boolean -- hence the execute() call fails because a boolean != PDOStatement

Comment: yes , sorry i didn't pay attention (didn't use PDO for long time)

Answer (score 0):

`bindParam` is not a language function. It is a [method of the PDOStatement object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

```
 $replace->bindParam(":email_str", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

It would be better if instead of using `$replace` as your variable name, you call it something like `$stmt` so that it is more apparent what that object is.

Alternatively, you can pass your parameter at execution. By writing your code like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES (?)");
if ($stmt)
{
    // Execute query with parameter
    $stmt->execute(array($email));
}
else
{
    // Could not prepare statement
    echo $db->errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: I now get this error instead: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()